# Casting Boolean Values to data frame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to cast boolean values to the given data frame.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, "Yes", 3, "NO"],
                   'B': [5, "true", False, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['tRue', 'nO', 'false', 'd', 'e']})
print (df)
```

I want to pass below fuction to dataframe, but not sure how to do so.

```
def str2bool(v):
    if v.lower() in ('yes', 'true', 1, '1'):
        return True
    if  v.lower() in ('no', 'false', 0, '0'):
        return False
```

is there any way to pass this fuction on Dataframe or any efficient method?

Expected OP:

[image]

Comment: What happens with things like `8,9, 'd','e'`?

Comment: We need those values, Please see an image of the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast to str before comparison and get rid of the int in the tuple:

```
def str2bool(v):
    if str(v).lower() in ('yes', 'true', '1'):
        return True
    if  str(v).lower() in ('no', 'false', '0'):
        return False

    return v
```

---

```
print(df.applymap(str2bool))
       A      B      C
0  False      5   True
1   True   True  False
2   True  False  False
3      3      8      d
4  False      9      e
```

Comment: Nope This is not correct. I need other value in df. i just want to cast only the values mentioned in tuple

Comment: Please suggest if any other efficient method without function.

Comment: @OO7 maybe also try `df.replace(["(?i)yes|true","(?i)no|false"],[True,False],regex=True).replace([0,1],[False,True])` and see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the function to the entire dataframe usinf `df.applymap`. But some edits need to be made to the function as well to avoid it throwing errors and to make it return the original value if the conditions aren't met:

```
import pandas 
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, "Yes", 3, "NO"],
                   'B': [5, "true", False, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['tRue', 'nO', 'false', 'd', 'e']})

def str2bool(v):
      if str(v).lower() in ('yes', 'true', '1'):
          return True
      elif str(v).lower() in ('no', 'false', '0'):
          return False
      else:
          return v

df.applymap(str2bool)
```

Output:

```
|    |     A |     B | C     |
|---:|------:|------:|:------|
|  0 | False |     5 | True  |
|  1 |  True |  True | False |
|  2 |  True | False | False |
|  3 |     3 |     8 | d     |
|  4 | False |     9 | e     |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the function to specific columns, if necessary.

```py
def str2bool(column_name):
    col = []
    for x in df[column_name]:
        if str(x).lower() in ['yes', 'true', 1, '1']:
            col.append(True)
        elif str(x).lower() in ['no', 'false', 0, '0']:
            col.append(False)
        else:
            col.append(x)
    return col
```

If you want to apply it on column A:

```py
df['A'] = str2bool('A')
```